# Simplifying second order chain rule

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative

In these notes: http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcIII/ChainRule.aspx

We have

$$\text{If } y = f(x(t)), x = g(t)$$

$$\text{Then } \dot y  = \dot{f}(x(t)) =\dfrac{ \partial f}{\partial x}\dot x$$

**I want to find the expression for $\ddot y$**

I tried to do it straight:

$$ \ddot y  = \ddot{f}(x(t)) = \dfrac{d[\dfrac{ \partial f}{\partial x}]}{dt}\dot x + \dfrac{ \partial f}{\partial x}\ddot x$$

Can we simply $\dfrac{d[\dfrac{ \partial f}{\partial x}]}{dt}$ further?

Comment: Your notation is confusing. You can use simply $x', y', f'.$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes by applying a second time the chain rule you get $$\dfrac{d[\dfrac{ \partial f}{\partial x}]}{dt}=\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^2} \dot{x}.$$